# close fancybox after delay

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox, delay

A client has me updating his static site with a few videos. He wants them to "pop up" and play on the site. I love fancybox mostly because I **suck** at jquery and it makes adding lightboxes so simple. I immediately installed that and so far everything is 100% perfect.

But he wants the fancybox window to close automatically after the clip is played. Since there are only a few videos and they are really short, I was going to just assign the time for each one. I think the longest is 1 min 30 sec and 5 videos in all.

How could I implement that? The fancybox site says "Within an iframe use - `parent.$.fancybox.close();`", but I have no idea how to make that work off of a delay in jquery. Any input or ideas would be awesome.

Comment: did you try with setTimeout('parent.$.fancybox.close();', 1000);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of Javascript's setTimeout functionality.

So something along the lines of:

```
setTimeout('parent.$.fancybox.close();', <time_interval>);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function to close all fancybox afterload and set timeout for that function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
closefancybox();
});

function closefancybox() {
    $.fancybox({
        afterLoad: function () {$.fancybox.close();}
    });
    setTimeout(function () { closefancybox(); }, <time_interval>);
}
```